# Using IORef in threepenny gui

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui, ioref

I'm trying to set an IORef in threepenny-gui but I can't get it to work. In my app the IORef itself will be more complicated and not itself be displayed - but this example demonstrates the problem I think.

Here is my try:

```
testIORef2 :: IORef String -> Window -> UI ()
testIORef2 ref window = void $ do
    return window # set title "Test IORef"

    inCell <- UI.input
    outCell   <- UI.input

    getBody window #+ [
            column [
                grid [[string " In cell::", element inCell]
                     ,[string "Out cell::"  , element outCell  ]]
            , string "Cells should update while typing."
            ]]

    -- When value changes write to IORef
    on  UI.valueChange inCell $ \_ -> do
        inValue <- get value inCell
        liftIO $ writeIORef ref inValue    

    -- Read the IORef
    refVal <- liftIO $ readIORef ref

    -- Behaviour which holds the string value in the input cell
    inValue <- stepper "0" $ UI.valueChange inCell
    -- Behaviour which holds the value in the ref
    let outValue = (const refVal) <$> inValue

    -- Set the value of the output cell to the outValue
    element outCell # sink value outValue
```

The code sort of works but the outValue is not quite up to date.

How do I fix it so that the updates are on time. Also, any improvements to the code would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is probably not what you intended to do. The line

```
let outValue = (const refVal) <$> inValue
```

specifies that `outValue` is a `Behavior` whose value is constant and equal to `refValue`. In turn, the latter value is obtained from

```
refVal <- liftIO $ readIORef ref
```

which means that its the value stored by `IORef` at this point in time in the `UI` monad.

---

When using `IORef`, you want to read the value of the reference when something changes, and use this value to modify the UI content, for instance like this:

```
on  UI.valueChange inCell $ \_ -> do
    inValue  <- get value inCell
    liftIO $ writeIORef ref inValue
    outValue <- liftIO $ readIORef ref    
    element outCell # set value outValue
```

For reasons of consistency (order of operations), it is not advisable to use an `IORef` as a source for a `Behavior` — it's either the latter or the former.

Comment: But in that code you could just write element outCell # set value inValue. There's no need for a ref. What I was trying to do was have separate code for setting up the inCell and outCell - so the inCell setup function saves an IORef and the outCell setup function reads the ref.

Comment: Well, you have to know when the `IORef` is written to in order to know when to read it and update the dependencies. In a way, that's what a `Behavior` does, though its more restricted, as it excludes `IO` actions, as their order would matter. In your case, you could register two events with `on UI.valueChange`: one that writes the IORef, and one that reads it.

Comment: Thanks. Got this working now using the 'on' function. Now going to try to convert to the FRP side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on threepenny-gui, but here's my guess.

The code you write *outside* the `on` event handler is executed just once. You therefore want to include the `outValue` update *inside* said handler, e.g.

```
-- When value changes write to IORef
on  UI.valueChange inCell $ \_ -> do
    inValue <- get value inCell
    liftIO $ writeIORef ref inValue    
    ... -- compute outValue
    element outCell # sink value outValue
```

Comment: The outValue does get updated when I refresh the page. So, maybe the code outside the on handler just gets run once on a refresh...